# criar uma triggers no mysql que reorganize a numeração de um campo quando um desses campos seja excluido

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela ***usuarios*** contendo a seguinte coluna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

observem que a numeração posição está em ordem, o que eu quero é quando excluir algum usuário a `trigger` reorganize a numeração, ou seja se excluir Josefa e Pedro, Jone passe a ser posição 2 e Soares passe a ser posição 3.

Comment: Pode explicar o motivo de você precisar disto? Se você usa este campo apenas para ordenação não há necessidade de reavaliar os valores.

Comment: uso esses campos para realizar outras operações que precisam estar na sequencia

Comment: poderia pegar o key do array, o problema começa com zero

Comment: @RobsonGuedesAlves usa um rank pra isso? não seria melhor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não conheço como funcionam triggers no MySQL, mas em teoria, vc só precisa decrementar todas as posições abaixo da que você removeu, é um SQL simples:

```
update usuarios set posicao = posicao - 1 where posicao < ?
```

Onde "?" é a posição do usuário que foi removido.

Comment: vou testar a solução é boa, vlw